# error: unknown filesystem

Tags: release-freya, boot, system, filesystem

I was happily watching a TV show episode and 5 minutes later I am with a fried computer. I am going step by step with what just happened:

I was using VLC when suddently the video stopped working and after 10-20 seconds a warning message from VLC popped up, said something like it couldn't reproduce the file.

Then everything started freezing really fast, I could barely do one task, minimize and maximize some windows and 10 seconds later the system completely froze.

I forced shutdown the computer holding the button and started it again. It starts, shows the Acer logo, then the Windows startup menu, I press Escape so Grub can show up, here's where I have elementary OS as well as Ubuntu. Surprise. Frozen black screen and Grub does not show up. After a few seconds I get a screen saying `error: unknown filesystem. Entering rescue mode...` and a `grub rescue>` prompt.

I shut down and restart again 3-4 more times and the same thing keeps happening. Then the 4th or 5th time I restart the computer not even the Windows startup menu is showing up, it just froze at the Acer logo. Shutdown again and now the Windows menu is up, press Escape, and same story with Grub. It's gone. Again that error.

I shutdown again and it stalls for a while in the Acer screen but finally the Windows menu shows up. And I'm like well "would even Windows work?". Nope, it doesn't. Trying to start Windows just brings back the Acer screen and it's locked there as I am typing this.

So here I am, with a totally fried computer where I have all my work and tools I need everyday.

I need urgent help, please.

edit: when I start up the computer there's a weird cracking repeating sound. Fried hard drive?

edit2: now after the Acer screen it says PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable. PXE-M0F: Exiting Broadcom PXE ROM. No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Answer (score 1):

This looks the hard drive has failed while using VLC. The unknown filesystem part shows that there is data corruption (maybe even your files). And when Windows goes corrupt it shows even more damage.

With those noises you've got an HDD failiure . And when it says `No Bootable Device` your HDD has completely failed. You may or may not be able to get back your files without data recovery service. Try booting in a few days and see if it boots. Check for broken sata cables etc.Also I would like to know your pc model and if it has being failing with S.M.A.R.T

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like an hardware failure as both the Windows boot manager has trouble, and as your EFI/bios indicates, it seems to be an issue with your harddrive. To test this, you could boot using a USB stick and see if the problem persists (you could try to backup your hdd with the live mode!).